Is it possible for readl() and writel() to block?
Can the Linux kernel functions readl() and writel() be blocked for some reason, such as during SPI communication.
ARM v7 architecture processors, The kernel of Linux 3.10.
kernel code:
static inline u32 readl(const volatile void __iomem *addr)
{
    return __le32_to_cpu(__raw_readl(addr));
}


static inline void __raw_writel(u32 b, volatile void __iomem *addr)
{
    *(volatile u32 __force *) addr = b;
}


Short answer: yes.  For example readl will block when reading from a socket if there are no bytes available locally ... and the stream hasn't closed.   And there are other scenarios.

It also depends whether you count a readl calling waiting a few milliseconds for a local disk read as blocking.

@StephenC If it is just reading and writing SPI related registers, will it be blocked?

AFAIK, you don't use readl / writel to read and write SPI registers. That's done using ioctl calls. Or am I wrong?  Please explain how you would be doing this; e.g. by showing us some example code.

Anyway ... if you have a specific question about readl and writel in SPI, you shouldn't write it as a question about blocking read / write >in general<.   Which is what you have literally done.
